# how to save a webpage as pdf in java?

Tags: java, jsp, html2pdf

I have a page that built with JSP, struts and jQuery that its data come after page loading.

I want to save the page as PDF-file with all contents and the same format with a button click. I can convert HTML to PDF and if I can save the page with all contents, I can convert to PDF.

The users can load the page with any browser and I want sth to act in all browsers.

How to save a page with this properties as pdf?

Comment: Do you want the static or the dynamic content to be converted?

Comment: Install FreePDF and just print into it.

Comment: I can not install any thing on user's computer

Answer (score 0):

Your button, will need to capture the output from the jsp using the same URL and then pass the written HTML to something like flying saucer.

Comment: I can not use URL because the page run on user server and I dont have access to URL

Comment: @andromeda: Does this mean you're not in a position to modify the server-side code?

Comment: I am developing a program for another ones!